# Has anyone created a DataContract testing tool?

Tags: wcf, unit-testing

Has anyone seen a library that tests WCF DataContracts? The motivation behind asking this is that I just found a bug in my app that resulted from my not annotating a property with the DataMember attribute - as a result, that property wasn't being serialized.

What I have in mind is an API that, given a particular type of DataContract, will automatically populate its members with random data, including any child DataContracts, then serialize it via one of the WCF Serializers/Formatters and then check that all of the data has been carried across.

Anyone?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's simple enough to use `DataContractSerializer` to serialise your object to a `MemoryStream`, then deserialise it back into existence as a new instance.

Here's a class that demonstrates this round-trip serialisation:

```
public static class WcfTestHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Uses a <see cref="DataContractSerializer"/> to serialise the object into
    /// memory, then deserialise it again and return the result.  This is useful
    /// in tests to validate that your object is serialisable, and that it
    /// serialises correctly.
    /// </summary>
    public static T DataContractSerializationRoundTrip<T>(T obj)
    {
        return DataContractSerializationRoundTrip(obj, null);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Uses a <see cref="DataContractSerializer"/> to serialise the object into
    /// memory, then deserialise it again and return the result.  This is useful
    /// in tests to validate that your object is serialisable, and that it
    /// serialises correctly.
    /// </summary>
    public static T DataContractSerializationRoundTrip<T>(T obj, 
                    IEnumerable<Type> knownTypes)
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(obj.GetType(), knownTypes);
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        serializer.WriteObject(memoryStream, obj);
        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        obj = (T)serializer.ReadObject(memoryStream);
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Two tasks that you are responsible for:

- Populating the instance in the first place with sensible data.  You might choose to use reflection to set properties or supply a constructor with its arguments, but I've found this approach just won't work for anything other than incredibly simple types.
- Comparing the two instances after you have round-trip de/serialised it.  If you have a reliable `Equals/GetHashCode` implementation, then that might already be done for you.  Again you might try using a generic reflective comparer, but this mightn't be completely reliable.

Comment: After passing a test of data contract object using the above method, I attempted to use the real client/server implementation and still got the following msg: "The input stream contains collection items which cannot be added if the instance is null".  Any idea how that is getting thru the test?

Comment: @slolife, you'll have to make sure the `obj` you're passing into the unit test contains the same kinds of items in that collection as are causing the problem you're seeing. The mention of `null` in the error suggests your collection is not being initialised for some reason. If you are still stuck, as a new question with more information (and link to it here if you like.)

Comment: Thank you for this answer! It can easily be adapted for Json serialization by using DataContract**Json**Serializer

Answer (score 0):

A better approach: create a proxy that serializes/deserializes all arguments when calling a method. Code can be found here: http://mkramar.blogspot.com/2013/01/unit-test-wcf-with-serialization.html