# Unit tests to catch InvalidDataContractException in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, unit-testing, serialization

I'm looking for a way to unit test all the DTOs I'm sending back over my WCF interfaces.  I want to avoid run-time errors like the following:

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException 
No set method for property 'Bar' in type 'Foo'.
```

For example in the following I would want the unit test to catch the above exception.

```
[DataContract]
public class Foo
{
    [DataMember]
    public decimal Bar { get { return 0; } }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Has anyone created a DataContract testing tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970828/has-anyone-created-a-datacontract-testing-tool)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a useful helper in this SO article that'll help you to test serialization deserialization using the NetDataContractSerlializer. You could call this helper from your unit tests.

[Has anyone created a DataContract testing tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970828/has-anyone-created-a-datacontract-testing-tool)